# Is there a way to center the item in the middle of the layout

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center an item in the middle of the layout while also, if possible have ability to control its position if need be with minor css tweaks.  In my layout page I cannot figure out why the item I want in the middle of the screen both horizontally and vertically is positioned to the left of the screen.  I know the issue is something in my layout I just can't seem to find out what the issue is.  Below is a basic version of my layout with the item I can trying to center.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html, body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
}

.layoutPage {
    min-height: 95%;
}

/***********************************
 ************Header*****************
 ***********************************/

.headerImage {
    background: blue;
    padding: 1.75em;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 3.5em; /*4em*/
}

/***********************************
 ***************Body****************
 ***********************************/

.bodyContainer {
    overflow: auto;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 12px; /*12px*/
}

.appRoundedShadow {
display: inline-block;
height: auto
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="layoutPage">
        <div class="headerImage">            
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="bodyContainer">
            <div class="appRoundedShadow">
  <div class="container">
   <div style="width: 450px; margin: 0 auto; border: 1px solid;">

                    <div style="margin: 2px; border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-width: thin; background-color: blue; text-align: center;">
                        <span style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 19px; color: #fff">Report</span>
                    </div>
                    <div style="margin: 1em">
                        <span style=""><input type="text" name="year"><br></span>

                        <input type="submit" id="executeReport" name="SubmitBtn" class="submitButton" value="Execute Report"/>
                    </div>
                    
                    
                    <div style="margin-left: 1em">
                        <p>It may take 2 or more minutes to complete your request.<br/></p>
                    </div>

                </div>
  </div>
 </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <hr />
        <span class="footerText">Copyright © </span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to center the entire appRoundedShadow div

Comment: It's a bit unclear what item you are trying to center. Is it the entire .appRoundedShadow div or some other component? Sometimes vertical centering is challenging. I have found flexbox to be useful in similar circumstances.

Comment: the entire appRoundedShadow div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got to do a couple things here. First, remove the `<br>` that's currently below the `.headerImage` div, because it's adding extra space that makes the `.headerImage` appear like it's not centered vertically.

Then, add the following for `.appRoundedShadow`:

```
.appRoundedShadow {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Then, make the padding consistent around `.bodyContainer` (replace it's `padding-bottom` with `padding`).

Finally, remove the `min-height` on the `.layoutPage`. Let the div's contents determine the height instead.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html, body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
}

/***********************************
 ************Header*****************
 ***********************************/

.headerImage {
    background: blue;
    padding: 1.75em;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 3.5em; /*4em*/
}

/***********************************
 ***************Body****************
 ***********************************/

.bodyContainer {
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 1em;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 12px; /*12px*/
    position: relative;
}

.appRoundedShadow {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="layoutPage">
        <div class="headerImage">            
        </div>
        <div class="bodyContainer">
            <div class="appRoundedShadow">
  <div class="container">
   <div style="width: 450px; margin: 0 auto; border: 1px solid;">

                    <div style="margin: 2px; border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-width: thin; background-color: blue; text-align: center;">
                        <span style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 19px; color: #fff">Report</span>
                    </div>
                    <div style="margin: 1em">
                        <span style=""><input type="text" name="year"><br></span>

                        <input type="submit" id="executeReport" name="SubmitBtn" class="submitButton" value="Execute Report"/>
                    </div>
                    
                    
                    <div style="margin-left: 1em">
                        <p>It may take 2 or more minutes to complete your request.<br/></p>
                    </div>

                </div>
  </div>
 </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <hr />
        <span class="footerText">Copyright © </span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To center your report add this style...

```
.bodyContainer {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific.  What about centering it not just horizontally but vertically as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can give the element you wish to center 'display:block' and 'margin:auto'

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html, body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
}

.layoutPage {
    min-height: 95%;
}

/***********************************
 ************Header*****************
 ***********************************/

.headerImage {
    background: blue;
    padding: 1.75em;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 3.5em; /*4em*/
}

/***********************************
 ***************Body****************
 ***********************************/

.bodyContainer {
    overflow: auto;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 12px; /*12px*/
}

.appRoundedShadow {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="layoutPage">
        <div class="headerImage">            
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="bodyContainer">
            <div class="appRoundedShadow">
  <div class="container">
   <div style="width: 450px; margin: 0 auto; border: 1px solid;">

                    <div style="margin: 2px; border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-width: thin; background-color: blue; text-align: center;">
                        <span style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 19px; color: #fff">Report</span>
                    </div>
                    <div style="margin: 1em">
                        <span style=""><input type="text" name="year"><br></span>

                        <input type="submit" id="executeReport" name="SubmitBtn" class="submitButton" value="Execute Report"/>
                    </div>
                    
                    
                    <div style="margin-left: 1em">
                        <p>It may take 2 or more minutes to complete your request.<br/></p>
                    </div>

                </div>
  </div>
 </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <hr />
        <span class="footerText">Copyright © </span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That just centers it horizontally not vertically.  It also removed my rounded shadow.

Comment: You should be me more specific with what exactly you want to achieve.
Maybe this can get you where you wanna go http://howtocenterincss.com/ :)

Answer (score 0):

Take `display: inline-block` off `.appRoundedShadow` and you're done.

Comment: That seems to center it it horizontally but stretches out the outer div to the width of the screen.